# Writing end-of-transmission to stdin of a running process

Tags: c, bash, stdin

I have a multi-threaded process that waits for input from stdin to shut down cleanly:

```
//launch worker threads

fgetc(stdin);
run  = 0;

//let threads shut down cleanly
```

From the terminal that I launched the process from, I can simply hit ENTER and the process will end.

However, if I try to write to that process's stdin from another terminal via

```
$ echo "\r" > /proc/<PID>/fd/0
```

\r will appear on the screen of the terminal running the processes, but the process still hangs on

```
fgetc(stdin);
```

I then tried to send the end-of-transmission character

```
$echo "\x04" > /proc/<PID>/fd/0
```

with no luck -- what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/proc/<PID>/fd/0` is a symlink to the terminal the process's stdin is connected to. For example, `ls -l` might show `/proc/<PID>/fd/0 -> /dev/pts/9`.

Trying to write to that link does not mean you'll write to the process's stdin; it means you'll write to whatever terminal that process is reading from. Your echo command is equivalent to `echo "\r" > /dev/pts/9`.

(By the way, you need to write either `echo -e "\r"` or `echo $'\r'` to write a carriage return. Also on UNIX end-of-line is delimited by `\n` not `\r`. You can actually just write `echo` to output a newline since it appends one automatically.)

I'd recommend finding a different way to signal your process to exit. The easiest method is to have it listen for `SIGTERM` (sent by `kill <PID>`) or `SIGINT` (sent by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) and shut itself down when signalled.

Comment: Thanks -- listening for signals is definitely a much cleaner solution.